# symbol lookup error undefined symbol using WSF

Tags: c++, wso2, apache-axis, wsh, axis2c

I am getting this at runtime:

`./LibTestApp: symbol lookup error: libaxis2_mod_addr.so: undefined symbol: axis2_handler_create`

on command `user1@ubuntu:nm path/libaxis2_mod_addr.so | grep axis2_handler_create`
the output is:`U axis2_handler_create`where U confirms that it's undefined.

on command `user1@ubuntu:ldd path/libaxis2_mod_addr.so`
i get:

`linux-gate.so.1 =>  (0xb7787000)

    libaxis2_axiom.so.0 => /opt/wso2/wsf_cpp/lib/libaxis2_axiom.so.0 (0xb7749000)

    libaxutil.so.0 => /opt/wso2/wsf_cpp/lib/libaxutil.so.0 (0xb771e000)

    libc.so.6 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0xb7553000)

    libaxis2_parser.so.0 => /opt/wso2/wsf_cpp/lib/libaxis2_parser.so.0 (0xb754a000)

    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0xb752f000)

    libdl.so.2 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0xb752a000)

    /lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0xb7788000)

    libguththila.so.0 => /opt/wso2/wsf_cpp/lib/libguththila.so.0 (0xb7519000)`

No one of this linked libraries contains `axis2_handler_create` and no one is linked with libaxis2_engine witch contains disired symbol(axis2_handler_create).

Is this a bug from WSF generate on building the framework described by missing the link to needed library? Or am i missing something? Any ideas how can i solve my problem?

**EDIT:**

Forgot to mention, code that load this library have been generated by [wsdl2cpp tool](http://wso2.com/project/wsf/cpp/2.0.0/docs/manual_content.html#15__WSDL2CPP_Tool) based on Onvif WSDL files from [here](http://www.onvif.org/onvif/ver20/util/operationIndex.html). In my case it's just [devicemgmt.wsdl](http://www.onvif.org/onvif/ver10/device/wsdl/devicemgmt.wsdl) and [media.wsdl](http://www.onvif.org/onvif/ver10/media/wsdl/media.wsdl).

Comment: You need to link your application (or have your build system) to the file that contains the definition. See all the hits on SO when searching for "undefined reference"

Comment: I tried to link my executable with axis2_engine.a. Not working.

Comment: "not working"? at what point? it doesnt link? it still hast the missing symbol? and the symbol is definetly in there? and you had the correct linker/compiler call?

Comment: I am getting the same error described earlier. At runtime.